# shell script ls globbing question

Tags: ls, glob

I am trying to use:
`ls -la *randomString*` in my shell script
to list out all the files and directories that contain a substring: "randomString"

everything works fine except when it encounter a directories that matches the substring, when it does it will give me something like this: 
(lets say the directory name was "TTrandomStringTT")

-rw-r-----   1 myName none           7 Jan 17 17:57 .YrandomStringY.txt

TTrandomStringTT:
total 16

drwxr-s--x   2 myName none        4096 Jan 17  18:00 .

drwxr-s--x   3 myName none        4096 Jan 17  19:00 ..

what I want it to do is list

drwxr-s--x   2 hctsui   none        4096 Jan 17 18:19 TTfrandomStringTT

just as a normal `ls -la` would do

I am really new to shell so I really need some help
thankyou so much for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your glob matches a directory name, it will list the contents of the directory.  If you don't want that to happen, do `ls -lad *randomString*`

Comment: @Shellscriptbeginner, so **accept** this answer already -- that's what the checkmark icon under the number and up/down arrow icons for this answer is **for**, and it's a crucial part of SO's etiquette!

Comment: oh sorry I didn't know that, I just joined. I thought the arrow up was the one that does that, but when I click it it say i dont have enough rep

Comment: @Shellscriptbeginner - that's ok, we're all here to learn.  I thought you already knew because you'd accepted the answer to the other question you'd asked.

Answer (score 2):

another way you can use is find, which recursively search for you.

```
find . -iname "*randomstring*" -ls
```